# Determination of Intermediate Scattering Function in numerical simulation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, fourier-transform, correlation-functions, molecular-dynamics

The Fourier transform of single particle density :
$$\rho(\textbf{k},t)=\int\rho(\textbf r,t)\exp(-i\textbf k.\textbf r)d\textbf r=\sum_j \exp(-i\textbf k.\textbf r(t))$$
The Intermediate Scattering Function(ISF) is defined as :
$$F(\textbf k,t)=\frac{1}{N}\Big<\rho(\textbf{k},t)\rho(-\textbf{k},0)\Big>.$$
The quantity $\rho(\textbf{k},t)$ is a complex quantity.  My question is : while determining ISF (i.e, $F(\textbf k,t)$  ) in numerical simulations shall I use the real part of $\rho(\textbf{k},t)$ only ? Or, shall I use the magnitude of $\rho(\textbf k,t)$ ?